# Is ParHashMap faster in lookup operations than HashMap?

Tags: scala, dictionary, par

Is ParHashMap faster in lookup operations(look for an element) than HashMap?

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap lookup is supposed to be O(1). If you did not have enough buckets, there may be a little linear search involved (within an overflowing bucket).

I cannot see how this could be parallelized.

You get benefits from a parallel collection when you want to operate on *all* (or a large number of) elements at once (for example with a `map`). Then each bucket can be processed by a different thread.